# How can nltk naivebayes classifier learn more featuresets after the train ends?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, nltk, naivebayes

I'm now making the nltk_classifier classifying sentence's category.

So I already trained classifier using 11000 sentences' featuresets.

```
train_set, test_set = featuresets[1000:], featuresets[:1000]
classifier = naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

But I want to add more (sentence,category) featuresets for upgrading classifier.
The only way I know is that I append featuresets to list of alreay learned featuresets. That way would make new classifier. But I think that this method is not efficient because It took a lot of time to train one or less more sentence.

Is there any good way to improve classifier's quality by adding featuresets???

Comment: I don't think there is a method dedicated to update an already trained model with additional data. It might still be possible, given that the NB model is pretty simple. Have a look at the implementation and see how the weights are updated during training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. Naive Bayes is usually super fast. It only visits all your training data for one time and accumulates the feature-class co-occurrence stats. After that, it uses that stats to build the model. Usually it's not a problem to just re-train your model with new (incremental) data.
2. It's doable to not redo the steps above when new data comes as long as you still have the feature-class stats stored somewhere. Now you just visit the new data the same way as you did in step 1 and keep updating the feature-class co-occurrence stats. At the end of day, you have new numerators (`m`) and denominators (`n`), which applies to both class priors `P(C)` and the probability of feature given a class `P(W|C)`. You could derive the probabilities by `m/n`.

Friendly reminder of Bayesian formulas in [document classification](https://github.com/muatik/naive-bayes-classifier):

-- Given a document `D`, the probability that the document falls in category of `C_j` is:

```
P(C_j|D) = P(D|C_j)*P(C_j)/P(D)
```

-- That probability is proportional to:

```
P(C_j|D) ~ P(W1|C_j) P(W2|C_j) ... P(Wk|C_j) * P(C_j)
```

based on:

- naive bayes assumption (all words, e.g., `W1, W2, ..., Wk` in the doc are independent),
- throwing away `P(D)` because every class have the same `P(D)` as denominator (thus we say proportional not equal to).

-- Now all probabilities on the right side could be computed by a corresponding fraction (`m/n`), where `m` and `n` are stored (or can be derived) in the feature-class co-occurrence matrix.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. But I cannot catch up with 2nd idea that you gave(**keep updating the feature-class co-occurrence stats**). When I get a new data, I could change it to featuresets(It would be same with feature-class co-occurrence stats ex.{'hi':True},{'hello':True}) and I need to **update** it to featuresets that I already made. Then, I suppose that this process needs to train from start? In other words, I suppose need to execute again code that I wrote in the question.

Comment: This is the second way that I understand. if I have C1,C2 category and get new C1,C2 category data, I can multiply probability that do not consider probability of priors(ex. P(C1_old|D)/P(C1)*P(C2_new|D)/P(C2)). And then I should get prior P(C1&C2) and multiply it to P(C1_old|D)/P(C1)*P(C2_new|D)/P(C2). if this way is right, how can I get corresponding fraction P(C1&C2)(m/n)?